Value from one dictionary matches key of another dictionary
I want to patch a record, but I need to verify whether it will update.
Otherwise, I get an HTTP 403 error.
How do I return the patch dictionary when the verification is true?
Verification has two parts:

patch_dict['equip_id] is in verify_dict.keys()
verify_dict value has a valid_str

valid_str = ['Not', 'Unique']
patch1_dict = {'id': 123, 'equip_id': 100}
patch2_dict = {'id': 123, 'equip_id': 150}
verify_dict = {'id':123, 'equip_150': 'From Template', 'equip_100': 'Unique'}

patch1_dict passes verification, but
patch2_dict will not.
My attempt of creating the dictionary comprehension:
{k:v for (k, v) in patch1_dict.items() if v in verify_dict for sub_v in valid_str}


Your code example seems to suggest equip_150 and equip_100 are identifiers, but did you mean for them to be strings? And does "patch1_dict pass" because the verify_dicthas the keyequip_100and its value is invalid_strwhilepatch2_dictdoes not becauseequip_150does not have a value that is invalid_str`?

yes, to the second question. I don't understand the first question. What is an identifier? I start with an Excel sheet with the changes for the patch. equip_150 is a column in the Excel. I read the Excel into a list[dict]. Each Excel row is a dictionary. I cannot patch the row if one of the columns violates an integrity rule. That is why I do the verification. verify_dict tells me which columns are updatable given their "Not" or "Unique" values.

Identifier means variable name. You didn't quote equip_id, so it will try to get its value as a variable.

Right. I convert the equip_ids to strings. I tried to simplify the notation of the problem because the actual API names are cumbersome.

You also need to quote id. It should be {'id': 123, 'equip_id': 100}

Sorry, I drafted this in notepad.

What is the expected result of the dictionary comprehension?

It looks like you need to do 'equip_' + patch_dict['equip_id'] to get the key to check in verify_dict.

What's the question? Check out [ask] and [edit] to clarify.

There are some valid questions in the comments here that you should address. I also think you may have a bit of an XY problem here. What exactly do you plan to do with the resulting dictionary (that you would end up with once the comprehension works as intended)?

There's no need for a loop. You need to construct the appropriate key in verify_dict from the value of equip_id in patch_dict.
def verify(patch_dict, verify_dict, valid_str):
    equip_key = f'equip_{patch_dict["equip_id"]}'
    return patch_dict['id'] == verify_dict['id'] and verify_dict.get(equip_key) in valid_str

valid_str = ['Not', 'Unique']
patch1_dict = {'id': 123, 'equip_id': 100}
patch2_dict = {'id': 123, 'equip_id': 150}
verify_dict = {'id':123, 'equip_150': 'From Template', 'equip_100': 'Unique'}

print(verify(patch1_dict, verify_dict, valid_str)) # True
print(verify(patch2_dict, verify_dict, valid_str)) # False


If you merely try to test if some dictionary passes given the verify_dict:
verify_example = {'id':123, 'equip_150': 'From Template', 'equip_100': 'Unique'}
valid_example = ['Not', 'Unique']

def test_dict(d, v: dict, valid: list) -> bool:
    return d['id'] == v['id'] and v[f'equip_{d["equip_id"]}'] in valid


patch1_dict = {'id': 123, 'equip_id': 100}
patch2_dict = {'id': 123, 'equip_id': 150}
print(test_dict(patch1_dict, verify_example, valid_example))
print(test_dict(patch2_dict, verify_example, valid_example))

Output:
True
False

This works because for:
d['id'] == v['id'] and v[f'equip_{d["equip_id"]}'] in valid


the IDs have to match and
f'equip_{d["equip_id"]}' constructs the needed key like equip_150 if d["equip_id"] is 150
v[equip_<n>] has to be in the list of valid strings


Hm, I'm noting that the solution is very similar to Barmar's - I'll leave it here for the explanation, but feel free to accept his earlier answer since the solution is nearly identical.

What to do when someone answers your question @markus1998
